# Compensation program for bug reports in MacOS and MS Windows?

Tags: operating-systems, bug

I have read that Apple gives compensation to people who found a BUG in MacOS. If that is true, does also Microsoft have a compensation program for people reporting verifiable and reproducible bugs in Windows?

Comment: Where have you read it? Usually companies have reward programs for **serious** security issues… bugs just have a report form to fill in, with no notification as to whether it's ever fixed, let alone a reward for reporting it.

Comment: Google says https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/msrc/bounty